# how can i get an ID of a button in php without knowing the ID name upfront

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a ban account system using PHP. Firstly I have a search function where I put in some characters, when i click on search it shows all account names containing these characters. I don't know upfront how many account names will be displayed. Behind every account name i have a button with the attribute name = "BAN" and an attribute ID; which is variable (it shows the account name id that is given in the SQL database). So what i want to do now is ban an account using the id that i gave to the button. is there any way i can get the id value into a PHP variable without know upfront what button is clicked?

this is my html/PHP:

```
                while($searchedaccounts = mysql_fetch_assoc($searched)) {
                $id = $searchedaccounts["user_id"];
                $username = $searchedaccounts["username"];
                $email = $searchedaccounts["email"];
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td data-th = 'User ID' >";
                    echo $id;
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td data-th='Username'>";
                    echo $username;
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td data-th='Email'>";
                    echo $email;
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td data-th='Email'>";
                echo "<button type='submit' name='ban' id='ban$id'>Ban</button>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
```

Comment: You could make the name of the button unique like your ID

Comment: I thought of that. but i don't know upfront how many id's there will be so I don't know for which ID's i have to write a $_POST.

Comment: create a hidden form item, and set number of Id in it

Comment: Alternatively to what @shahab suggests use a javascript based ajax request instead of a simple form submission. This also saves you from having to make a full reload.

Comment: if possible for you can blend php code with javascript and with it send id to your server, but the way that @Naruto says is correctly more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<button type='submit' class='DeleteBan' name='ban' id='ban$id' data-rowid='$id'>Ban</button>";

<script>
    $(".DeleteBan").click(function() {
        var Id=$(this).attr('data-rowid');
        $.ajax({url:"DeletePage.php?Id="+Id,cache:false,success:function(result){
            alert('one row deleted');
        }});
    )};
</script>
```

**DeletePage.php**

```
<?
$Id=$_GET['Id'];

$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE idColumnName='$Id'";

//Write Mysql Command To Delete This Query

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for get id of button

```
$("button").click(function() {
alert(this.id); // or alert($(this).attr('id'));})
```

Comment: this problem is that i need the variable in php and not in javascript, and i don't feel like using get to pass that value.

Comment: if you need value in php variable . You do it using AJAX

Comment: where do you want to display that 'id' in your code ? @MathiasCochet

Comment: I don't want to display it. I want to delete a row using the ID.

Comment: if you want to delete a row using this ID you send ajax request with this id for any php page  for row delete

Answer (score 0):

you can make your button like this:

```
<button type='submit' class="ban" name='ban' id='ban$id'>Ban</button>
```

and use jquery to get the value:

```
$(".ban").click(function() {
var getval = $(this).attr('id'); 
})
```